# Multiple Forms with Different Actions using Submit Buttons

Tags: php, forms, button, submit

I have Two forms in my index.php and am trying to get them to submit and POST their data seperatly

Form 1

```
echo '<form action="process.php?type=news" method="post">';
echo '<table cellspacing="0"><tr><th>';
echo 'Add News to News Feed';
echo '</th></tr><tr><td>';
echo 'Title:<br /><input name="newstitle" type="text" id="add" style="height:16px;width:525px;" size="80" maxlength="186" /><br />';
echo 'Main Body Text:<br /><textarea name="newsfeed" id="add" style="width:525px;height:78px;" maxlength="2000" ></textarea>';
echo '<input style="float:right;margin-top:5px;" id="button" type="submit" value="Submit" />';
echo '</td></tr></table></from>';
```

And Form 2

```
echo '<form action="process.php?type=suggest" method="post">';
echo '<table cellspacing="0"><tr><th>';
echo 'Suggest Additions to the Intranet';
echo '</th></tr><tr><td>';
echo '<textarea name="suggest" id="add" style="width:330px;height:60px;" maxlength="800" ></textarea>';
echo '<input style="float:right;margin-top:5px;" id="button" type="submit" value="Submit" />';
echo '</td></tr></table></from>';
```

I want these both to post and do the action after pressing the submit button, but currently the second form submit to the first forms action

How can i fix this???

EDIT: Also i am using .PHP for both the index and process page then using it to echo the forms onto the page

Also here is the process.php data

```
$type=$_REQUEST['type'];
$suggest=$_POST['suggest'];
$newstitle=$_POST['newstitle'];
$news=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['newsfeed']);

if ($type == "news")
{
  $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM newsfeed WHERE title = ('$newstitle')");
  $number_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
  if ($number_of_rows > 0)
  {
    echo 'This Title is Already Taken';
  }
  else
  {
    $sql="INSERT INTO newsfeed (title, news) VALUES ('$newstitle','$news')";    
    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
    {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
  }
}
elseif ($type == "suggest")
{
  $sql="INSERT INTO suggestions VALUES ('$suggest')";
  if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  header('Location: index.php');
  exit;
}
```

Comment: Why do you break it into so many echos?

Comment: @Jared It makes it easier for me to see where the bits of the table is for editing

Comment: You could still linebreak in the middle of the string without adding a new echo.

Comment: where do you set `$type` within the process.php file, also you should move over to prepared querys. **Also your form is ending `</from>`**

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Lol i didnt see that spelling mistake, thanks, that fixed it

Comment: @AdamCoulson , i hope that you are aware that in php you can do `?><some></html><?php` .. echoing large chunks oh html in this way is considered to be a bad practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that you are not closing the form with `</form>`, but with `</from>`, so the code of the second form is in fact still **inside** the first form since the tags are never closed?

Comment: Yes, was ending with </from> not </form>

Answer (score 0):

try giving the submit an on click for each form so in its submit buttons html put this:

`onclick="document.forms["myform1"].submit();"`
and for form 2 put
`onclick="document.forms["myform2"].submit();"`

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure exactly what you would like to achieve, so heres my assumptions,
1. your form submits wrongly, eg, second form submits the first form's data
or
2. you would like to do both submits 1 after another.

FOR 1:

Do this.

```
<form id="form1" action="process.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="news">
....
</form>
```

Note the spelling 
    /form not /from

```
<form id="form2" action="process.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="suggest">
....
</form>
```

Note the spelling 
    /form not /from

Comment: Ive fixed it, spelt </from> not </form> also doing this means i have to change the way i get my $type in the process.php but as i also use links to go to the process.php `<a href="process.php?type=something">Something</a>` this would defeat the purpose

Answer (score 0):

**Some pointers:**

Instead of echoing out so many times, echoing out once is suffice! Remember echos slow down your script. Also I would not pass the type as a $_GET, post is always safer for forms, you can use a hidden field to add the type:

```
<?php 
echo '
<form action="process.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="news">
...
...
</form>';//Not </from>
?>
```

Then with the PHP part use a switch case instead of if elses, it will be easier to add features then splitting with another ifelse, plus the default block can be used for anything that dont match like the last else in an if else statement.

```
<?php 
$type = $_POST['type'];

switch($type){
    case "news":
        ...
        break;
    case "suggest":
        ...
        break;
    default:
        //default if different type or no type is set
        break;
}
?>
```

Also move over to PDO or prepared mysqli_ functions for your mySQL stuff its safer.